# Android : Make image opaque / transparent

Tags: android

Greetings,

I would like to place an image over a surfaceview. However I would like the image to be transparent so you can see the image and also the undlying surfaceview. Can anyone suggest how I could do this?

Comment: Use a png with an alpha channel?

Comment: will look into it. Never tried something like this before :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I do it before drawing my shapes.

```
Bitmap buffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
buffer.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```